# Compute Ext with Macaulay2

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, math-software, macaulay2

> I want to compute Ext with Macaulay2.

I see in the website they write how to do it, but I can not do it. Can anyone help me with an example?

For example, let $S=k[x,y,z,t]$. How to compute $\mathrm{Ext}^i_S (S/(xy^2,x^2z),S)$ for some $i$? How to interpret it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> S = QQ[x,y,z,t]
>
> M = module S/ideal "xy2,x2z"
>
> for i from 0 to 4 list Ext^i (M,S)

In general, if you have installed M2 property, viewHelp  would direct you to a help page, and help  would give you a short help message in M2.

Comment: Many thanks. But im not able to interpret the answer.can you help

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Youngsu. The answer is : o4 = {image 0, cokernel {-1} | x |, cokernel {-5} | xz y2 |, 0, 0}. Here, what is $Ext^1$, what is$ Ext^2$,.., ? (probably OP wants to know this too.)

Comment: Yes user1. ,,,,

Comment: The results are separated by commas. I recommend you to read the instruction for tutorial for Macualay2 which explains things like your question. For instance, if you only one a particular spot of the ext you can use $Ext^i (M,S)$. But in your example, all the other Exts are already zero.

Comment: http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.5/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_modules_spin_sp__Macaulay2.html

Comment: I think it is your job to go over the basic instruction regarding Macaulay2. Otherwise, I suggest you to change your question asking what the Ext modules are instead.